# jQuery getting an Element by Class of the parent

Tags: jquery, html, dom, selector

my HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="container1">
This is the Element i want to toggle
</div>
<div class="container2">
<a href="#" class="button">Click</a>
</div>
</div>
```

I want to toggle the container1 by clicking the button. The thing is there are several of these structes, so i can't use an ID. I need to use the event.target function in jquery, but i don't know how to get the parent element and the "container1" element in the parent element and how to toggle it with slideToggle.

Comment: It depends, is it always the previous sibling of the button container that you want to toggle? If so, you could just do a `.parent().prev('div')` to get from the `<a>` to the `.container1` div. The parent goes to .container2, then .prev('div') selects .container1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps for this case you could use something like

```
$('.button').click(function(){
    $(this)
        .parent()
        .siblings()
        .first()
        .toggle();
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RubenGeert/TgT9Z/1/) for a tiny demo.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: good catch, I thought the OP was mainly about the selector.

Comment: Personally, I would not have chosen this answer as the correct one as it is the most fragile. It depends on the exact structure (instead of selector matching), which is always a bad idea for maintenance. Well done anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('.button').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
      $(this).closest('.wrapper').find('.container1').toggle();
});
```

Comment: +1: Although the use of `on` is less readable than `click` in this instance, this is my favorite answer. It is the most likely to survive HTML changes (and it correctly disables the anchor click).

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.button').click(function(){
  $(this).parent().siblings('.container1').toggle();
});
```

Comment: Or perhaps `.parent().siblings().first().toggle()`. Kinda depends on what the html may/may not look like.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) and [siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings) here:

```
$('.button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.container2').siblings('.container1').toggle(); 
})
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eGUc9/)**

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie not true. Without it you will be scrolled to the top of the window

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 $("a").on("click",function(e){
     var el=$(this); // this will be a element
     el.parents(".wrapper").find(".container1").toggle();
    });
```

"parents" - this will get you parent element with class "wrapper"
"find" - this will find child element with class "container1" inside wrapper

If you bind to event with jquery then "this" scopes to target element. You can also get target from event argument "e.target"

here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/25vaT/

Comment: `closest` would always be preferable to `parents` in this situation. You don't need/want a search back to the DOM root.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie you are correct. Perf comparison can be found here http://jsperf.com/jquery-parents-vs-closest/8

Comment: Perf stats aside (that is useful though), stopping when you find a first match is obviously going to be faster than searching every parent, back to the root, for any/all matches :)

Comment: I agree. But answer should be used more as a concept (you wouldn't select all "a" elements either), not as something you copy/paste to solution. You can easily traverse to destination element using only vanilla javascript - if you wish to squeeze out max performance :)

Comment: You know, I did not even spot your use of "a"... not good when `class="button"` was provided. Aside from those issues I do prefer your specific selectors though as they are more robust to HTML changes :) Jai's answer is the "most correct" of this bunch (IMHO), although `click` would be preferable as his `on` is not delegated anyway (like yours).

Comment: Click is shorthand for on("click") (http://api.jquery.com/click/). You can read good pros/cons between those two here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122078/difference-between-onclick-vs-click . I prefer on/off syntax, because it's more intuitive and it gives you possibility for event namespacing. e.g. on("click.mynamespace") and off(".mynamespace")